# Is it Necessary to Create a New Component for Static Displays?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

My website will have an About page, which will have its own route. I hope to simply use app-routing-module while keeping the header and footer on the screen (in app-component) rather than reloading.

However, I am not sure how to do this except by loading a component with an empty class, linked to a template and style sheet with all the display information. Is it possible to simply have router-outlet output static HTML without creating a new component?

Comment: Instead of a component, you could use header/footer as usual html in your app-comp

Answer (score 0):

no there is no way to present it as you want, since what you are calling static HTML in a component is not html, it is javascript code that is rendered on the client as HTML, the only html page that exists inside an angular proyect is the main page, so for your solution you have to create a component and reference it on your router.